# Terran Reaper Build Order

Tags: starcraft-2, sc2-build-order

Just wanted to know. How do you go about rushing reapers? I've been experimenting on 9 and 10 but almost always ends up with an enemy protoss having stalkers or terran marauders.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate a little bit more on your built order. Are you gathering enough resources, what else are you doing, are you scouting to see what the others are doing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, a fast Reaper rush is most effective against Protoss. Against Terran, they may have 2-3 Marines before your reaper gets there, which will make it ineffective. Against Zerg, you will often have to deal with a Queen or multiple Zerglings on creep. Protoss, though, requires a Cybernetics Core along with a Stalker to be able to combat it.

Here is the [Turbo Reaper Build](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Turbo_Reaper_%28vs._Protoss%29) most commonly use against a Protoss opponent.

Another option against Zerg is to use a build that LzGamer has been using lately, which is to build 3 Rax quickly and pump reapers from all of them. This applies huge pressure because the Zerg opponent can't take on large groups of Reapers without speed upgraded Roaches. I don't have an exact build for this one, but there is some discussion by Zerg players about how to combat it [here](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=141549).

Hope this helps some.

Comment: Thanks man. Wish I'd read this sooner before jumping in my placement matches and using reapers on terran.

Comment: Linked build is already obsolete: you can't build rax before supply anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The thing about reapers, is that they're fairly predictable (in terms of a good opponent anticipating it if they know you're terran).

Against any decent player, they'll ready a Stalker, Marauder, or Queen to handle any reaper harass. That means you have a relatively small window for the rush to be effective.

If your enemy has stalkers / marauders by the time your reapers reach their base, you've taken too long. What's your general build order? Check your replays -- what's the game time when your first reaper comes out? What maps are you trying to do this on?

Comment: Tried to do it on every map. Unfortunately didn't work out as well with some of them especially ones where I couldn't scout early enough to set a proxy rax near the enemy base.